# App in python together with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, kivy

my goal is to create  a simple App  based calculator -which converts  from one currency to another but thing is that conversion rate should be   automatically retrieved from website. for this purpose i  decided to use kivy library.based on the following example :
[kivy calculator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-calculator-using-kivy-python/)
i have managed  to change some little part  and got the following  code and result :

here is code of .py file and .kv file

```
`import kivy

# base Class of your App inherits from the App class.
# app:always refers to the instance of your application
from kivy.app import App

# this restrict the kivy version i.e
# below this kivy version you cannot
# use the app or software
kivy.require('1.9.0')

# for making multiple buttons to arranging
# them we are using this
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

# for the size of window
from kivy.config import Config

# Setting size to resizable
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 1)


## Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
## Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')


# Creating Layout class
class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):

    # Function called when equals is pressed
    def calculate(self, calculation):
        if calculation:
            try:
                # Solve formula and display it in entry
                # which is pointed at by display
                self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))
            except Exception:
                self.display.text = "Error"


# Creating App class
class CalculatorApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()


# creating object and running it
calcApp = CalculatorApp()
calcApp.run()`
```

and corresponding .kv file

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32

# Define id so I can refer to the CalcGridLayout
# class functions
# Display points to the entry widget

``<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry
    rows: 6
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10



    # Where input is displayed
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False

    # When buttons are pressed update the entry
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "7"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "8"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "9"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "$"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(2.54)

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "4"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "5"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "6"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "yen"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'*'+ str(54.21)

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "1"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "2"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "3"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "euro"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(2.8070)

    # When equals is pressed pass text in the entry
    # to the calculate function
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "AC"
            on_press: entry.text = ""
        CustButton:
            text: "0"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "="
            on_press: calculator.calculate(entry.text)
        CustButton:
            text: "GBP"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(3.1790)
    BoxLayout:
        CustButton:
            font_size: 20
            text: "Scientific calculator"
            on_press: entry.text = ""

`
```

when i am running .py file, i am getting this result :
[result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnMU2.png)

but thing is that if  we look at code :
  `text: "GBP" on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(3.1790)`
GBP is static, if i want to  use beautifull soup to get this data from web, how to combine  result to  our class? please give me a hint

Edited: as there  was unclear comments about  previous question  that it is unclear what i am asking, i will repeate question :
look on the code below :

```
 text: "GBP"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(3.1790)
```

instead of  writting exchange rate directly, how can i read it from website and include in kivy  , what is unclear here? look  for instance following link :
[Exchange rates](https://www.tbcbank.ge/web/ka/web/guest/exchange-rates?p_p_id=exchangeratessmall_WAR_tbcpwexchangeratessmallportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-5&p_p_col_count=1)

can you see information about GBP? how to get    this and  include in kivy? i know that i can get it through beuatifulsoup, but how include in kivy, is it  clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DictProperty` instance variable in your `CalcGridLayout` class to store exchange rates after scraping and use that in the .kv file. The exchange rates are updated every minute on a separate thread in background.

```
def get_exchange_rates():
  # code where you scrape using beautifulsoup and return a dict of 
  # exchange rates
  return {}


class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
  exchange_rates = DictProperty(get_exchange_rates())

  def _update_exchange_rates(self):
    while True:
      self.exchange_rates = DictProperty(get_exchange_rates())
      time.sleep(60). # update every minute

  # Function called when equals is pressed
  def calculate(self, calculation):
    if calculation:
      try:
        # Solve formula and display it in entry
        # which is pointed at by display
        self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))
      except Exception:
        self.display.text = "Error"


class CalculatorApp(App):
  def build(self):
    layout = CalcGridLayout()
    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=layout._update_exchange_rates)
    update_thread.daemon = True
    update_thread.start()
    return layout
```

Use `exchange_rates` in your .kv file like this:

```
CustButton:
  text: "GBP"
  on_press: entry.text = entry.text + '/' + str(calculator.exchange_rates['GBP'])
```

Comment: could you please upvote my question so that i can upvote your solution

Answer (score 1):

based on help from @Sourabh, i have updated my code like this :

```
import threading
import time
import kivy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# base Class of your App inherits from the App class.
# app:always refers to the instance of your application
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
# this restrict the kivy version i.e
# below this kivy version you cannot
# use the app or software
kivy.require('2.1.0')

# for making multiple buttons to arranging
# them we are using this
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

# for the size of window
from kivy.config import Config

# Setting size to resizable
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 1)


## Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
## Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')

#get exchange rate
def get_exchange_rates():
  # code where you scrape using beautifulsoup and return a dict of
  # exchange rates
  myrates =dict()
  link = "https://www.tbcbank.ge/web/ka/web/guest/exchange-rates?p_p_id=exchangeratessmall_WAR_tbcpwexchangeratessmallportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-5&p_p_col_count=1"
  doc = requests.get(link).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
  dolar = soup.find_all("div", class_="currRate")
  rates = []
  for i in range(1, 6, 2):
      rates.append(dolar[i].text.strip())
  myrates["USD"] =rates[0]
  myrates["EUR"] = rates[1]
  myrates["GBP"] = rates[2]
  #getting  yen
  link = "https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=500&From=GEL&To=JPY"
  doc1 = requests.get(link).text
  soup1 = BeautifulSoup(doc1, 'html.parser')
  tag = soup1.find("div", class_="unit-rates___StyledDiv-sc-1dk593y-0 dEqdnx")
  yen=tag.p.text.split("=")[1].strip().split(" ")[0]
  myrates['Yen'] =yen

  return myrates

# Creating Layout class
class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
  exchange_rates = DictProperty(get_exchange_rates())

  def _update_exchange_rates(self):
    while True:
      self.exchange_rates = DictProperty(get_exchange_rates())
      time.sleep(60)# update every minute

  # Function called when equals is pressed
  def calculate(self, calculation):
    if calculation:
      try:
        # Solve formula and display it in entry
        # which is pointed at by display
        self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))
      except Exception:
        self.display.text = "Error"


class CalculatorApp(App):
  def build(self):
    layout = CalcGridLayout()
    update_thread = threading.Thread(target=layout._update_exchange_rates)
    update_thread.daemon = True
    update_thread.start()
    return layout


# creating object and running it
calcApp = CalculatorApp()
calcApp.run()
```

and corresponding .kv file :

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32

# Define id so I can refer to the CalcGridLayout
# class functions
# Display points to the entry widget
<CalcGridLayout>:
    id: calculator
    display: entry
    rows: 6
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10



    # Where input is displayed
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: entry
            font_size: 32
            multiline: False

    # When buttons are pressed update the entry
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "7"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "8"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "9"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "$"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(calculator.exchange_rates['USD'])

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "4"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "5"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "6"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "yen"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(calculator.exchange_rates['Yen'])

    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "1"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "2"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "3"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "euro"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(calculator.exchange_rates['EUR'])

    # When equals is pressed pass text in the entry
    # to the calculate function
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        CustButton:
            text: "AC"
            on_press: entry.text = ""
        CustButton:
            text: "0"
            on_press: entry.text += self.text
        CustButton:
            text: "="
            on_press: calculator.calculate(entry.text)
        CustButton:
            text: "GBP"
            on_press: entry.text =entry.text+'/'+ str(calculator.exchange_rates['GBP'])
    BoxLayout:
        CustButton:
            font_size: 20
            text: "Scientific calculator"
            on_press: entry.text = ""
```

if we run :
[image: currency calculator]

it works fine, for instance let us try following example :
[image]

when i clicked on yen button, i got normal division. thanks one's again @Sourabh